# How to Stop Timer Android

Tags: android, service, timer, android-context, timertask

following is my code:

In MainActivity.class

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener alert_on_off_listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup groupname, int CheckedButtonId) {

         if(CheckedButtonId==R.id.radiobutton_on){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "radio on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             alert_on = true;
             display_alert();    
         }
         else{
             alert_on = false;
         }   
    }
};

public void display_alert(){

    int delay = 10000;  
    Timer timer =new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HoraWatchActivity.this,MyService.class);
                startService(myIntent);
            }
    }, delay,10000);
}
```

MyService.class

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    if(MainActivity.alert_on)
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert is On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert is Off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I am checking the `onCheckedChangeListener` and calling `display_alert` function according to the checked radio button.

In `display_alert` function I was using timer scheduling at fixed rate of 10 seconds and calling `myservice` class.

So once I checked the `radio_on` button, it calls my `display_aler`t function and got the "alert on" in toast. So its working fine.

If I again check `radio_off` button and then check the `radio_on` button, I am getting the "alert on" toast, but the toast is coming twice. Similarly if I again select the `radio_on` button, the toast is displaying for the third time, but I need only once. This was due to  that the timer is running for every 10 seconds. I want to stop the timer once I click the `radio_off` button.

The problem is, once I started the timer, I was not stopping it further. When and how shall I cancel the timer tasks in my class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, create your TimerTask on a separate way:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HoraWatchActivity.this,MyService.class);
    startService(myIntent);
  }
}
```

Declare it somewhere, of course visible to your OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
MyTimerTask myTimerTask;
```

Schedule it:

```
public void display_alert() {
  int delay = 10000;  
  myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, delay, 10000);
}
```

And then modify your code to:

```
private OnCheckedChangeListener alert_on_off_listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup groupname, int CheckedButtonId) {

     if(CheckedButtonId==R.id.radiobutton_on){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "radio on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         alert_on = true;
         display_alert();    
     }
     else{
         myTimerTask.cancel();
         alert_on = false;
     }   
}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(timerTask!=null){
    timer.cancel();
}
```

you can use the code to stop/cancel timer

Answer (score 3):

First create a class extends TimerTask, make object of it and handle the operation on that object.

```
int delay = 10000;  
Timer timer =new Timer();
myTimer mTask= new myTimer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTask, delay, 10000);

public class myTimer extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HoraWatchActivity.this,MyService.class);
            startService(myIntent);         
    }
}
```

when your mTask works get over just

```
 if(mTask!=null){
    mTask.cancel();
}
```

thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to stop a timer and a task using following code:

```
    if(null != timer)
    {

        timer.cancel();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Number of cancelled tasks purged: " + timer.purge());
        timer = null;
    }

    if(task != null)
    {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Tracking cancellation status: " + task.cancel());
        task = null;
    }
```